# Get ALL exceptions that can result from int(some_variable)

Tags: python, exception

I do not want to do:

```
try:
    pid = int(a_variable)
except StandardError as e:
    pass
```

So, the question is what is the method of figuring out **all of the possible exceptions** can result in `int(a_variable)`. Obviously, `TypeError` and `ValueError` can happen, but how do I work out what else *can* result?

Comment: @falsetru see updated last sentence, sorry

Comment: Do you wanna know all the possible exceptions that can happen or how to handle other exceptions than `TypeError` and `ValueError` ?

Comment: How would you case a TypeError? `sys.argv` is defined as list of strings, and strings do not raise TypeErrors when converted to int.

Comment: I'm confused why you need this. You should catch the errors you anticipate, not any error that could theoretically happen. What if conversion to int could raise a `ProcessorBurningError`?

Comment: @ByteCommander I should not have just pasted code, meant something else (any variable really, not `sys.argv[1]`).

Comment: @timegb: one reason is curiosity - Java has checked exceptions and figures it out automatically and I'm curious if there's a mechanism in Python that *could* do that, even if it does not have practical application. Another reason is that one might try to write code in some place that is supposed to be as robust as possible, handling every potential exception in the controlled manner (not saying that this should be standard practice, but there might be some places one may want to do that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pick the method that suits you from [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module and combine it with a logger object (see [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module):

```
import traceback
import sys
import logging
try:
    pid = int(sys.argv[1])
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(traceback.print_exc())
```

Execution examples:

You can catch an`IndexError` exception with `python begueradj.py`

```
begueradj@begueradj:~/Desktop$ python begueradj.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester.py", line 6, in <module>
    pid = int(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

You can catch a `ValueError` exception with `python begueradj.py +`:

```
begueradj@begueradj:~/Desktop$ python begueradj.py +
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester.py", line 6, in <module>
    pid = int(sys.argv[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '+'
```

Comment: I think this answer is actually answering the question posed.

Answer (score 1):

I only see two possible exceptions that can be generated by *your code*:

```
pid = int(sys.argv[1])
```

- **`ValueError`** if the string in `sys.argv[1]` is no valid integer representation (like "one" or "1.5")
- **`IndexError`** if the `sys.argv` list does not contain at least two elements, because the script was executed without command-line arguments.

There's no chance (assuming you don't override the builtins) that your code can raise a <del>**`TypeError`**</del>, because `sys.argv` is always a list of strings. Period.

You could eventually also even get a **`NameError`** if you forgot the `import sys` in your code above this line as well, but that's no runtime error but a programming error.

---

What *could* happen is that *while your command is running* the interpreter raises an unrelated exception like **`KeyboardInterrupt`** because the user pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in that exact millisecond - but you usually don't want to catch those locally.

---

As you're saying in your comment that the code line in your question was just an example, if we generalize this to `int(x)` (with `x` being a literal or a variable, but nothing that is able to throw exceptions itself, like method calls or operations), you can additionally get those exceptions:

- **`TypeError`** if the argument is neither a numeric type (int, long, float, complex, bool), nor a string-like type (str, bytes, bytearray) nor any other object having a `__int__` method or (since 3.4) a `__index__` method.
- **`NameError`** if you use a variable name as input which has not been defined yet in this context. However this is very unlikely unless you use `eval` or `exec` and let the user input a variable name (discouraged!). As this is a pure programming error and no runtime error and your IDE will highlight the use of undeclared variable names, it's usually not useful to check for this error.

Comment: Best answer than mine, but you forgot the possible cases of 1/ an `AttributeError` in the first case (if `sys` is bound to something that doesn't have an `argv` attribute), and 2/ just any possible builtin or custom exception in the second case if `x` has a broken implementation of `__int__(self)` - but both fall in the "programming error" category as far as I'm concerned, and we _dont_ want to catch programming errors anyway.